# Towards an understanding of DirectX syntax using pointers, pointers to pointers and references

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, directx

I am trying to understand pointers when used in DirectX, but can't quite grasp it yet.  I can't believe the syntax that gets used, it's very complicated.

In some invocations of a function, there are multiple uses of pointers and references, sometimes double-pointers.

Can you help me out a bit?

Let's say you have some functions called `CreateGizmoTron(xxx)`, and you want them to demonstrate both pointer and reference syntax (which DirectX uses all the time).  I'll use parameter types that I have actually seen:

```
CreateGizmoTron1(&alpha);
CreateGizmoTron2(pBeta);
CreateGizmoTron3(&pGamma);
CreateGizmoTron4((void**)&pDelta);
```

Would someone be kind enough to create functions that would use such parameters, and maybe a note or two as to why it is done this way?

It might require a bit of pre-code to set the right stage for something to actually compile.

Of course, I already know the basics of passing by reference and passing by values, but DirectX seems to do things its own way.

I just am missing this one piece of the puzzle, and right now it is all Greek (hence the parameter names).

If you can, just make the function simple, just adding the parameter to itself.  Under what context would any of these be used?

Comment: Isn't there a tutorial on using `DirectX`?

Comment: [Programming DirectX with COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com)

Comment: If you want a function to modify a value, then one way is to pass a pointer to that value as a parameter `&alpha`. If you already happen to have that pointer available then just pass the pointer itself `pBeta`. If the value you want to modify is a pointer, then you pass a pointer to a pointer, `&pGamma` (basically no different to the first case). Finally if your function is 'type challenged' then you might make the parameter a void pointer pointer, `(void**)&pDelta`. That seems dubious to me, but I don't know  COM. This seems normal C style programming, nothing particularly specific to COM.

Comment: Richard... Thanks.  That is basically what I was looking for.  COM uses a different paradigm than regular C++.

Comment: john.  Thanks as well.  I guess the meaning of (void**) threw me off, like is was something else.  Not something I have ever seen until DirectX, which uses the COM model.

Answer (score 3):

DirectX runs on top of COM.

In COM:

- passing an interface by single-pointer value (or passing anything else by const reference) is used for an `[in]` parameter. The parameter is input-only, as the function is not able to modify the caller's variable.
- passing an interface by single-pointer reference or double-pointer (or anything else by non-const reference) is used for an `[in,out]` or `[out]` parameter. The parameter is used for output, as the function is allowed to modify the caller's variable.

> Of course, I already know the basics of passing by reference and passing by values, but DirectX seems to do things its own way.

That is incorrect. Passing parameters in DirectX works exactly the same way as it does in C/C++, as one would expect. COM is compatible with C and C++. But references don't exist in C, so DirectX (and some implementations of COM) provides convenience wrappers for C++ to make C-style calls safer/easier.

Comment: I suspect the OP is mostly complaining about the DirectX methods that take **arrays of interface object pointers** which is why you see stuff like "address of" for parameters being applied to an interface pointer (i.e. ``void PSSetShaderResources(UINT StartSlot, UINT NumViews, ID3D11ShaderResourceView * const *ppShaderResourceViews);``).

Comment: Wow, Mr. Walbourn himself.  Absolute Godfather of DirectX, and Senior Engineer at Microsoft.  I'm honored.  Yes, this is what I was trying to say.  DirectX has a learning curve due to it using COM and stuff like GetAddressOf vs. operator&.  Incidentally, my next question on was over usage of "Slots".  What does it mean?  Is it the maximum number of items on the screen?  Is it the maximum number of buffers?  Even in a book (Zink's on DX), I don't see it explained.